# Boolean assigned to a regex method

Tags: c++, regex, boolean

I want a boolean assigned to a method so then depending on the ouput of that method i know whether to execute a following method or not, but it does not seem to like the way i am doing it.

Code is below

```
   bool ok = (boost::regex_match(str1,string_matcher))
              {
                  DCS_LOG_DEBUG("Correct Number of Passengers");
                  output.push_back("Correct Number of Passengers\n");
                  DCS_LOG_DEBUG("2nd loop done 1");

              }
              else
              {
                  a = st[0];
                  boost::regex const string_matcher1(splitMask[1]);
                  boost::trim(a);
                  if(boost::regex_match(a,string_matcher1))
                  {
                      DCS_LOG_DEBUG("Correct format for surnamce");
                      output.push_back("Correct format for surnamce\n");
                      DCS_LOG_DEBUG("2nd loop done 4");
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      DCS_LOG_DEBUG("Invalid format for surname");
                      output.push_back("Invalid format for surname\n");
                      DCS_LOG_DEBUG("2nd loop done 5");
                  }
              }
```

What am i doing wrong there or is it not possible? would be happy for any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing an if:

```
if (boost::regex_match(str1,string_matcher))
```

{ ...

OR:

```
bool ok = boost::regex_match(str1,string_matcher);

if (ok)
{ ...
```